# What is correct syntax for nested group by query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table containing:

```
OnDate
SystemUserId
ObjectId
EntityId
```

I'm trying to get a result set to show how many total unique objectId have been accessed per systemuserId and entityId

If I do a single systemuser and entity like this, it shows 83 results

```
SELECT DISTINCT objectid 
FROM public.auditlog
WHERE ondate >= current_date
AND ondate < current_date + 1
AND systemuserid = '97de2a93-737c-e311-8437-12d0d8a96a66'
AND entityid = '70816501-edb9-4740-a16c-6a5efbc05d84'
```

When i'm trying to group by though i'm getting 189, there must be duplicates.

Thanks

```
SELECT A.entityid, A.systemuserid, SUM(A.c)
FROM
(SELECT entityid,systemuserid,objectid, count(*) as c
FROM public.auditlog
WHERE ondate >= current_date
AND ondate < current_date + 1
AND systemuserid = '97de2a93-737c-e311-8437-12d0d8a96a66'
AND entityid = '70816501-edb9-4740-a16c-6a5efbc05d84'
GROUP BY entityid, systemuserid,objectid) A
GROUP BY a.entityid, a.systemuserid
```

Comment: `SUM(A.c)` just gives you the old value including the duplicates.  If you use `SUM(1)` or `COUNT(*)` in your query, you should get the same results as in @GordonLinoff's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `count(distinct)`?

```
SELECT entityid, systemuserid, count(distinct objectid) as c
FROM public.auditlog
WHERE ondate >= current_date AND
      ondate < current_date + 1 AND
      systemuserid = '97de2a93-737c-e311-8437-12d0d8a96a66' AND
      entityid = '70816501-edb9-4740-a16c-6a5efbc05d84'
GROUP BY entityid, systemuserid
```